# Can i change the style.xml for different resolution

Tags: android

How to change the style.xml for different resolutions, I know to find the resolution but no idea to change the style.xml for tablet

Comment: have a look here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html and here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 8):

Just create as many `style.xml` files as you want for different resolutions and place them in folders `values-mdpi`, `values-hdpi`, `values-ldpi` etc. This should do the job.

Comment: Thanks, but i need to implement this for tablet, in tablet we are having up to 10 inches, whether it will be working in that too

Comment: @Android, You can use values-xlarge folder for tablets.